# Select Option value does not get stored in database

Tags: php, laravel, select, laravel-5, input

Laravel view code:

```
<tbody>
  @foreach($drycleaning as $drycleaning)
      <tr>
        <td class=""><input type="text" size="5" name="dc_{{$drycleaning->id}}"></td>
        <td class="">
            <div><div class="form-group">
            <select id="projectinput5" name="p_dc_{{$drycleaning->id}}" class="form-control">
            <option value="" selected>Price of</option>
            <option name="p_dc_{{$drycleaning->id}}" value="{{$prices->shirt}}">shirt</option>
            <option name="p_dc_{{$drycleaning->id}}" value="{{$prices->pant}}">pant</option>
            <option name="p_dc_{{$drycleaning->id}}" value="{{$prices->top}}">top</option>
            </select>
            </div></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
@endforeach
</tbody>
```

Controller code:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

  $bill = Bill::create([
  'waf_1' => $request->waf_1,
  'dc_1' => $request->dc_1,
  'dc_2' => $request->dc_2,
  'dc_3' => $request->dc_3,
  ...
  'p_dc_1' => $request->p_dc_1,
  'p_dc_2' => $request->p_dc_2,
  'p_dc_3' => $request->p_dc_3,
  ...
  ]);

  $bill->save();
  return redirect()->route('sp.orders.index');
}
```

Because of the foreach in view, the input and dropdown select is shown 3 times. and only 3 entered input values are successfully saved into a database but not the selected option values. 
Can anyone help me understand my code mistake?

Comment: sidenote: an <option> doesn't have a name attribute, so `<option name="p_dc_{{$drycleaning->id}}"` is useless. (which doesn't solve your problem, I know)

Comment: you are sure the ids match (1,2,3)?

Comment: Yes.Am pretty sure the ids match. Not only 1,2,3 I have created and written all 50 of them in view, controller and database.

Comment: Have you added the columns to `fillable` property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the proper solution for you

**In your blade**

```
<tbody>
    @foreach($drycleaning as $drycleaning)
        <tr>
            <td class=""><input type="text" size="5" name="dc[{{ $drycleaning->id }}]"></td>
            <td class="">
                <div><div class="form-group">
                    <select id="projectinput5" name="p_dc[{{ $drycleaning->id }}]" class="form-control">
                        <option value="" selected>Price of</option>
                        <option value="{{ $prices->shirt }}">shirt</option>
                        <option value="{{ $prices->pant }}">pant</option>
                        <option value="{{ $prices->top }}">top</option>
                    </select>
                </div></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
</tbody>
```

**In you Controller**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $data = array();
    $data['waf_1'] = $request->waf_1;

    foreach ($request->dc as $key => $value)
        $data['dc_'.$key] = $value;

    foreach ($request->p_dc as $key => $value)
        $data['p_dc_'.$key] = $value;

    $bill = Bill::create($data);
    return redirect()->route('sp.orders.index');
}
```

Comment: i value is not always in sequence. $drycleaning->id can be random.

Comment: Check out my new answer. This will work for non-sequence. But i recommed you to use One to many database realtions in this kind of situation.

Comment: I already tried this syntax. 
In dd($request->all()); output it gives two arrays as 
"dc" => array:3 [▼
    4 => "5"
    5 => "7"
    6 => "9"
  ]
  "p_dc" => array:3 [▼
    4 => "8"
    5 => "7"
    6 => "43"
  ] But only "dc" array gets saved. That is what I am struggling with. I appreciate your efforts so far.

Comment: Thank You. Turns out few fields were not mentioned as fillable in the model file.

Answer (score 0):

I would make the name attributes an array because then you can have as many as you want and your ids aren't always going to be the same. Hopefully, this will get you going:

```
@foreach($drycleaning as $drycleaning)
  <tr>
    <td class=""><input type="text" size="5" name="dc[]"></td>
    <td class="">
        <div><div class="form-group">
        <select id="projectinput5" name="p_dc[]" class="form-control">
        <option value="" selected>Price of</option>
        <option value="{{$prices->shirt}}">shirt</option>
        <option value="{{$prices->pant}}">pant</option>
        <option value="{{$prices->top}}">top</option>
        </select>
        </div></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
```

@endforeach

then you can iterate through in your controller

Comment: shouldnt the `{{$drycleaning->id}}` do that (kind of) already?

Comment: You're 100% right, i didn't correctly edit the original snippet!